# How to enable Recursive (OpenType) font code ligature in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code, opentype

*More specifically*

How to enable code Discretionary Ligatures "dlig" feature of [Recursive font](https://www.recursive.design/) ?

Usual fontLigatures `settings.json` configuration doesn't work.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Recursive Sans Linear"
"editor.fontLigatures": true // Do not work :-/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable code ligatures edit VSCode `settings.json` with desired OpenType features :

```json
// Code ligatures ON
"editor.fontLigatures": "'dlig'"
// BONUS: other feature set (see below)
"editor.fontLigatures": "'ss01', 'ss02', 'ss03', 'ss04', 'ss05', 'ss06', 'zero', 'onum'"
```

[image: Recursive ligature features]

Sources :

[Stephen Nixon's article on recursive.design](https://www.recursive.design/process/)

[GitHub VSCode related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10435)

See also :
[Microsoft OpenType spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_ae#tag-dlig)

Comment: I have only tested dlig feature atm

Answer (score 1):

or, per the official recursive readme:

```
## Code Ligatures

By popular demand, these fonts shift the code ligature feature from their usual OpenType feature of `dlig` to the feature `calt`, to act more like preexisting code-ligature fonts such as Fira Code & Hasklig.

In the Desktop & Web fonts, code ligatures are still controlled by the `dlig` feature, so that they are *not* on by default for contexts in which they may not be well-understood by many users.
```

meaning:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "Rec Mono Casual",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.fontLigatures": "'calt'",
  "editor.fontWeight": "normal"
```